# How can I remotely/administratively confirm if an Outlook add-in is deployed and enabled on user systems?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office

I have an Outlook COM add-in / Exchange Client Extension that is installed on user desktops.  Occasionally over-zealous security measures on Office can disable this add-in.  Is there a way I can remote check to confirm if the add-in is installed and NOT disabled on user systems?

I was thinking of checking the registry for **HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/Addins//LoadBehavior** and making sure it's set to 3.

I'm not sure if that would necessarily help though or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are really looking for here is a workstation management and configuration tool.  They typically report all of the installed software packages and their complete settings.

While scanning the registry of each machine would tell you whether or not Outlook is loading addins it won't tell you if the addins are actually enabled or not.

You may have better luck checking out a group policy setting for Outlook and ensuring the addins setting is specified the way you want and that the add-in is in some type of allow list.

Comment: Great suggestion. I wasn't aware that workstation management tools could dig that deep.  I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Not that its a great tool for larger orgs but check out Spiceworks, it will at least give you some of the details you are looking for.  Otherwise you're looking at System Center or one of those guys.  GPO is something to check as well.